# Contract instance in console - return object when expecting return uint

Tags: solidity, web3js, console, uint256

I am running functions using an instance of a contract in a browser console. When I call a function that is supposed to return something, I get a return object, with a "words" property that contains the return value. However in the case of a large uint, I get an array with 2 separate numbers (see the screenshot below).

I get it has something to do with Javascript and big numbers, but how can I convert these values in the array to the uint value it corresponds to?

[image]

Comment: const prize = await contract.prize(); console.log(prize.toString());

Comment: if they are less than the MAX safe number in javascript then you can convert them to numbers. otherwise you will loss data and need to use BigNumber libraries to add , sub .....etc. #

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let result = await contract.prize()
result.toNumber()
```

or short
`(await contract.prize()).toNumber()`

Comment: Where does this fonction come from ? Google returns nothing official.